# Can QTreeWidget jump to a specific line(specified by QTreeWidgetItem or column)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I use setCurrentItem() to focus on a  specific item,but the QTreeWidget does not jump to the  specific item correspondingly.
Are there any function of QTreeWidget can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `scrollTo(const QModelIndex &index, ScrollHint hint = EnsureVisible)` function ([documentation link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#scrollTo)).

The `index` parameter is the index of the item that you want to bring into view
The `hint` parameter specifies where the item should be located after the operation (e.g. on top, in the middle, etc).

```
QTreeWidget w;
w.setCurrentItem(<your item>);
w.scrollTo(w.indexFromItem(<your item>)); // or w.scrollTo(w.currentIndex())
```

Comment: I only use the class of QTreeWidget,can I use this scrollTo function directly like this:`FaceLibTree->setCurrentItem(item);
                QModelIndex index = FaceLibTree->currentIndex();
                FaceLibTree->scrollTo(index);`   Its doesnt work.

Comment: @phuinews, QTreeWidget is derived from QTreeView

Comment: @ SingerOfTheFall,Thanks very much,I dont know this before! But I still dont know how to use the function to let the QTreeWidget jump to the currentItem.

Comment: @ SingerOfTheFall,Sorry,It works,I just used the wrong ScrollHint parameter.Thanks.

Comment: QTreeWidget has scrollToItem()

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollToItem() :
Link to the Qt doc : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#scrollToItem

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to do it. `scrollTo` requires an index, and there's no simple way to get an index for a given `QTreeWidgetItem`.